# Google Maps Distance Matrix Nodejs timeout

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-api-nodejs-client

We have an application that depends on Google maps distance matrix API to calculate distance and time between two points. It's a nodejs application. We have been using this [Google Maps Node.js Client](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js)

The application has been working okay. Now it times out. We have accepted the new pricing and terms of service that got into effect since July 16, added a billing account as well as generate a new key. We thought that could be the case but we are still getting a timeout error.

Our code is as follows:

```
const googleMaps = require("@google/maps");

let mapsClient = googleMaps.createClient({ 
    key: process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY, 
    Promise: Promise 
});

mapsClient.distanceMatrix({
    origins: fromLat + ',' + fromLng,
    destinations: toLat + ',' + toLng,
    mode: 'driving'
}).asPromise().then(res => {
    // Do something in case of success
}).catch(err => {
    // Do something else in case of error
    console.log('MAPS ERROR', err); // Prints out a timeout
});
```

I cannot figure out what we are doing wrong. Logging the error on catch prints out **timeout**. Please help.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem here. did you find any solution for this? if yes, please share your findings. :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have anyone found a solution for it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have anyone found a solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

Go to query editor -right click your web data source - Advanced Editor. This will give you access to M code behind it. You need to specify "timeout" interval in there manually. >>[timeout=#duration(0,0,30,0)])) This is a TimeSpan like parameter, with the values representing Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds.